# Is anything hidden under the sand in the Shipyard?

Tags: zelda-skyward-sword

In the Shipyard in *The Legend of Zelda: Skyward Sword*, after defeating the Thousand Year spider thing and searching through the sand, Fi told me that there was a **0% chance** there would be any clues in the sand and I should leave the area. But my intuition tells me there is a **75% chance** that the great Level Designer Gods hid some special treasure for me here, like a Piece of Heart or a Gold Rupee or *something*... and Fi is just trying to divert my attention back to the actual *plot*. BORING!

Should I keep searching through the sand in this location? Is there anything useful to be found?

(If there is and you tell me, please use a spoiler tag for what the actual treasure is)

Comment: There really isn't anything there. You should listen to her and report back to the Captain.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I didn't believe Fi either and I searched the sand from corner to corner. Turns out that there is nothing in the sand aside maybe a few hearts and a few green rupees, mostly what you'd expect from cutting grass.

There's really nothing of awesome value in there, so you might as well leave the area... doesn't mean you have to go back to the plot right away though!

Comment: Rats. I have been foiled again! :-)

Comment: Upvoted for the very subtle hint about an unrelated sidequest at the end.